# How to access an IIO device driver in linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I a noob to Linux device drivers.

I have an IIO driver with me (for OPT3001 ambient light sensor) , operating over the I2C bus, which has been compiled successfully in the kernel (version 3.18). The device tree is modified to match the compatible field, present in the driver.

The problem is how do I access this driver to get some data in the userspace ?

The driver has some callbacks for read and write registered in a structure. Should I call them directly in my C file ?

Comment: There is a library *libiio* with some tools already available in user space. Besides that you can communicate via *sysfs* interface on the devices of the IIO class IIRC */sys/class/iio*. More is available in in-kernel documentation.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the [Industrial I/O Utils](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iioutils/) project.

Answer (score 0):

you have differents possibilities :

- your driver provide a /dev node you can open in you C file.
- your driver provide informations through sysfs.

in case of a /dev node, you can have access to file operations (open, read, write, ioctl). you just have to open your file 1 time and each read() call will read the value from the sensor.

in case of sysfs, you should find the file to open/read in /sys/class/...

Comment: A variety of functions are registered within the structure. How do I make sure, which one gets called when I attempt to read the /dev node ?

Comment: here is a documentation about the file_operations.
https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c577.htm

If your driver use it, the structure is defined and the functions need to have clear name ( xxx_open, xxx_read, etc)
you can make a quick test with 'cat' :

    cat /dev/xxx

Answer (score -1):

You can use the userspace API provided by:

```
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
```

Using it you can open de bus /dev/i2c-X (X=0,1,2,...), set device address using ioctl call, and use read and write operations to read and write to/from the bus.

Also, you can install "i2c-tools" package (apt-get install i2c-tools), to install userspace tools like i2cset, i2cget and i2cdetect, very useful for testing the I2C bus and the device connected to it.

Comment: It’s a wrong way to access devices that have already drivers.